# Slick MappedTo[String] column can't use like

Tags: slick

I want to use MappedTo[String] as one column type. There is one query using like to select some records.

Sample code:

```
case class ID(value: String) extends scala.slick.lifted.MappedTo[String]

class Order(tag: Tag) extends Table[(ID, String)](tag, "order") {
  def id = column[ID]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def name = column[String]("name", O.NotNull)
  def * = (id, name)
}

val ordres = TableQuery[Order]

def all(implicit session: Session) = {
  ordres.filter(_.id like "2014.%").list
}
```

Compiler error:

```
[error]  value like is not a member of scala.slick.lifted.Column[models.ID]
[error]     ordres.filter(_.id like "2014.%").list
[error]                        ^
[error]  ambiguous implicit values:
[error]  both value BooleanColumnCanBeQueryCondition in object CanBeQueryCondition of type => scala.slick.lifted.CanBeQueryCondition[scala.slick.lifted.Column[Boolean]]
[error]  and value BooleanOptionColumnCanBeQueryCondition in object CanBeQueryCondition of type => scala.slick.lifted.CanBeQueryCondition[scala.slick.lifted.Column[Option[Boolean]]]
[error]  match expected type scala.slick.lifted.CanBeQueryCondition[Nothing]
[error]     ordres.filter(_.id like "2014.%").list
```

How to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I currently found, is to resort to [sql interpolated strings](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/sql.html)

```
//slick needs this to be able to convert to your custom wrapper type
implicit val GetID = GetResult(r => ID(r.nextString))

def all(implicit session: Session) = {
  sql"""select id, name from order where id like '2014.%'""").list
}
```

---

As a sidenote there is also a [startsWith](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/api/index.html#slick.lifted.StringColumnExtensionMethods@startsWith[R](s:String)(implicitom:slick.lifted.OptionMapper2[Boolean,String,Boolean,Boolean,P1,R]):slick.lifted.Rep[R]) method that can be used in filtering strings with lifted embedding, and it would've been more appropriate for your case; that is, if filter worked as expected.

Answer (score -2):

You should override the value definition. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32628389/slick-3-0-0-mapping-existing-models)

```
case class ID(id: String) extends scala.slick.lifted.MappedTo[String] {
   override def value: String = id
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution but the compilation would fail saying that: `Case class has to have a 'value' field`